# Value not updating on the HTML using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a controller in which a value gets randomly generated

```
app.controller('detailReadingCtrl',function(){
  var value = 0;
  $scope.dispValue = 0;

 setInterval(function(){
   value = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
   $scope.dispValue = value;
 }
});
```

and my html is

```
<div>{{dispValue}}</div>
```

The Value on the html is not getting updated with the changed value. The dispvalue is changing in the controller but it is not updating in the html. I want to see the value change for every second on the screen without the need of refresh.

I tried using $scope.$watch and also $scope.$broadcast both seem to not work. Please let me know if you have any ideas about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` doesn't trigger a `$digest` cycle, instead, use the `$interval` module:

```
app.controller('detailReadingCtrl',function($scope, $interval){
    var value = 0;
    $scope.dispValue = 0;

    $interval(function(){
        value = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        $scope.dispValue = value;
    });
});
```

And you had other errors in the code (`$scope` wasn't being injected, missing `)` at the end of the interval)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to see the change in the values. 

Thanks for the help. I removed the other errors too